# Cordova iOS app icon always shows default icon on iPad OS 13.7

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, icons, ios-icons

What is the correct sizes/setting for the icon on "Open Apps View" on iPad OS 13.7?

The circled icon cannot be replaced by `config.xml` with Cordova v9.0.0  on screenshot.

[image]

icons view in XCODE

[image]

config.xml

```xml
...

<platform name="ios">
        <preference name="Orientation" value="all" />
        <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
        <icon height="88" src="res/ios/icon-88.png" width="88" />
        <icon height="48" src="res/ios/icon-48.png" width="48" />
        <icon height="55" src="res/ios/icon-55.png" width="55" />
        <icon height="196" src="res/ios/icon-98@2x.png" width="196" />
        <icon height="172" src="res/ios/icon-86@2x.png" width="172" />
        <icon height="1024" src="res/ios/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <icon height="20" src="res/ios/icon-20.png" width="20" />
        <icon height="30" src="res/ios/icon-30.png" width="30" />
        <icon height="180" src="res/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="60" src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="76" src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="57" src="res/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="29" src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="res/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
...
```

`versions`

```
"cordova": "^9.0.0"
"cordova-android": "^6.4.0"
"cordova-ios": "^6.1.0"
MACOS v10.15.4
Xcode v10.15.0
```

build by `$ cordova build ios`

Answer (score 0):

turns out above icon setting works after I install app to another iOS device.
Seems like previously installed app cached the icon on iPadOS 13.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that changing only the file config.xml is not enough to have a different icon from the default one. Actually, for ios platforms, I see that changing the config.xml does not affect at all.

I have created an iconset from my own image by this tool: https://makeappicon.com/
This create different images and a file .json. You need the content of AppIcon.appiconset.

In your project folder go to platforms/ios//Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

You can delete this folder and paste the one you downloaded before.

This worked for me, I have a new icon and I tested it with iPad10 and iPhone14.